# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.1

i made a page view/maessage.php
      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">

```
  <script>
     function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:{'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
        });
     }
  </script>   
  <body>
   <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
     Click the button to replace the message.</div>
  <?php
     echo Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
  ?>
  </body>
```

in routes.php

```
Route::get('/ajax',function(){
  return view('message');
});
```

Route::post('/getmsg','AjaxController@index');

in AjaxController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
  $msg = "This is a simple message.";
  return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
   }
}
```

when i ran http://localhost:8000/ajax
http://localhost:8000/getmsg generate below error

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

> 1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: in
>   RouteCollection.php line 218 and buch of error.....

but when i saw in consol it show below error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53: in
>   VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53

i can't understand error .i am fresher in laravel. and i aactually don't know the meaning of '_token': `'{{ csrf_token() }}'` in message.php. pls. help to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This exception:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

is telling you that the method on your form is not the same as the method on your route.

So you have 2 options to solve this issue.

**First option : Change route method type**
Your route has a GET

```
Route::get('/ajax',function(){
  return view('message');
});
```

but your form has a POST

so change it to:

```
Route::post('/ajax',function(){
  return view('message');
});
```

**Second option: change your ajax-form method type**

```
Route::get('/ajax',function(){
  return view('message');
});


  <script>
     function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:{'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
        });
     }
  </script>
```

Regarding your question about CSRF . It protects against Cross Site forgery. You can read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf